# spinner in numeric input field, with bootstrap twitter and simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, input, simple-form

I'm trying to customize my simple_form numeric input field [image: screenshot of the spinner]

in the image there's an example of the input field generated, if I press the arrows on the right hand side, I'm able to increase/decrease the value.

This is a great feature, though I would like to be able to control the step of the increase, to be 0f 0.001, and the starting value as well.

I couldn't find any documentation about this, has anyone got any clue?

thanks, 
Giulio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `input_html` option to apply attributes to the input tag to achieve what you want.

In your case:

```
f.input :number, input_html: {value: '1.001', step:'0.001'}
```

You can see all available attributes for the number field here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that the spinner was provided directly by HTML, this solved it, thanks a lot.